# How to Say "Garden" in Korean, and root meanings?

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning

How do I Say "Garden" in Korean? Is it 정원? Sometimes google translate can be wrong, and does not use commonly used words.

정원

Also, does Garden derive from "정" meaning love/affection?

Comment: Have a you looked at a dictionary? Why do you think it's not 정원?

Comment: https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=garden&range=all

Comment: From naver's dictionary the Hanja for 정 in 정원 is 庭 and 정 meaning love/affection is 情, so no, Garden likely does not derive from it

Comment: hi @user17915 please write in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: I think for questions like this it is better to consult a dictionary. People might tend to downvote

Answer (score 2):

"garden" is 정원, as was answered in the comments.

정원 sounds a little formal though.  It is used more often for one in a public place or upscale house.

For an ordinary "yard" in a regular house, 뜰 is more common.  앞뜰 is front yard and 뒷뜰 backyard, for example.

Another word for "yard" is 마당.  뜰 suggests it is covered with plants and flowers, whereas 마당 does not.  마당 (and 앞마당, 뒷마당) is the most frequently used word for any large open space in the front or back of a house.